# Finding how many numbers are divisable by 5 in a range

Tags: c#

My task is: Write a program that reads two positive integer numbers and prints how many numbers p exist between them such that the reminder of the division by 5 is 0 (inclusive). Example: p(17,25) = 2.

```
Console.Write("Enter min: ");
            int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter max: ");
            int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The numbers devidable by 5 without remainder from {0} to {1} are: ",min,max);
            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                }
            }
```

This prints out the numbers that are divisable by 5 in the range...How do I count how many there are and print the count in the console?

Comment: If you know how to write a `for` loop then you should already know the answer.

Comment: ask your teacher or class mates.

Comment: Actualy we haven't learned loops yet. I just looked it up.

Comment: @user1639735 Then you should be reading it before posting questions. Programming is done by first reading some fundamental introductory book in addition to basic computer principles like binary representations, number representations, algorithm structures (selection, repetition etc.). Only then, when you exhaust all possible resources you should turn to stackoverflow.com for help. I must say that this is how you should do from my point of view.

Comment: Well, I have exercises after each chapter and the point is to solve them with the knowledge you have so far and if the solution requires something from the later chapters you google it. I just got stuck with this one and decided to post it here. Obviously this forum is for harder tasks than mine...

Answer (score 8):

For positive arguments you can do in O(1):

```
int DivisibleBy5From0To(int n)
{
    return (n / 5) + 1;
}

int DivisibleBy5FromTo(int lo, int hi)
{
    return DivisibleBy5From0To(hi) - DivisibleBy5From0To(lo - 1);
}
```

For possibly not positive arguments, you'd need to use `Math.Floor(n / 5.0)` instead of `n / 5`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe:

```
int numMod5Between = Enumerable.Range(first, second - first + 1)
                               .Where(i => i % 5 == 0)
                               .Count();
```

Comment: +1 for the answer although I'm not sure that this is what he is searching for. I'm pretty sure that OP is doing homework or is a newbie learning his first programming steps.

Comment: If using inq, in order to count how many are there might as well use Count as I suggested. And yeah, the real question is what is he trying to learn here.

Comment: Simply `Count(i => i % 5 == 0)` ?

Comment: @L.B: What is the advantage? I wanted to show that he can also use the `IEnumerable<int>` for something other than counting.

Comment: @TimSchmelter 1 less IEnumerable class.

Comment: @L.B: That's not an advantage. Since OP also needs to disiplay each number the `Where+Count` shows that Linq enables both.

Comment: @TimSchmelter OP actually hasn't learned loops yet. Your answer is not for showing him/her another way. It is because Linq answers gets more upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

```
Console.WriteLine(Enumerable.Range(min,max-min+1).Count(n => n % 5 == 0));
```

Comment: perhaps `Enumerable.Range(min, max-min+1)`?

Answer (score 2):

```
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                total = total + 1;
            }
        }
        //print total
```

Answer (score 2):

This is easy, when you have special case in a for loop, just increment a counter within it.

```
            Console.Write("Enter min: ");
            int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Enter max: ");
            int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("The numbers devidable by 5 without remainder from {0} to {1} are: ",min,max);
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                if (i % 5 == 0)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(i);
                    count++;
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Total number dividable by 5 is: " + count.ToString());
```

Comment: @user1639735 This is solution for your particular case, since you are learning and not really programming. Others have given more advanced solutions that are yet to be learned on higher semesters/later chapters and are available in C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
    int count=0;
    Console.Write("Enter min: ");
                int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter max: ");
                int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("The numbers devidable by 5 without remainder from {0} to {1} are: ",min,max);
                for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
                {
                    if (i % 5 == 0)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
Console.WriteLine(count);
```

You add a `count` variable, set it to 0 and increase it when you find a devidable number, in the end you print the `count`.

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Write("Enter min: ");
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter max: ");
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The numbers devidable by 5 without remainder from {0} to {1} are: ",min,max);
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 == 0)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(i);
                count++;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine(count);
```

The new lines being `int count = 0;` and `count++;` followed by `Console.WriteLine(count);`. The logic is every time `i % 5 == 0` is true then you increment count.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Console.Write("Enter min: ");
        int min = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter max: ");
        int max = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("The numbers dividable by 5 without remainder from {0} to {1} are: ", min, max);
        for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
        {
            if (i % 5 != 0)

            continue;
            Console.WriteLine(i);
```

This is another way of solving this with the use of a continue statement.cheers